# Find all substrings in a string in python 3 with brute-force

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, substring, brute-force

I want to find all substrings `'A' to 'B'` in `L = ['C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'X', 'B', 'Y', 'A']` with bruteforce, this is what i've done:

```
def find_substring(L):
    t = 0
    s = []
    for i in range(len(L) - 1):
        l = []
        if ord(L[i]) == 65:
            for j in range(i, len(L)):
                l.append(L[j])
                if ord(L[j]) == 66:
                    t = t + 1
                    s.append(l)
    return s, t
```

Now I want the output:

```
[['A','B'], ['A','B','A','A','X','B'], ['A','A','X','B'], ['A','X','B']]
```

But i get:

```
[['A','B','A','A','X','B','Y','A'],['A','B','A','A','X','B','Y','A'],['A','A','X','B','Y','A'],['A','X','B','Y','A']]
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: When you find a 'B' you need to `break` out of the inner loop.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp No, as you want all of them.

Comment: @JoeIddon Ok, I get it now.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp See my answer :)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the list `s`, holds references to the `l` lists.

So even though you are appending the correct `l` lists to `s`, they are changed after being appended as the future iterations of the `j` loop modify the `l` lists.

You can fix this by appending a copy of the `l` list: `l[:]`.

Also, you can compare strings directly, no need to convert to ASCII.

```
def find_substring(L):
    s = []
    for i in range(len(L) - 1):
        l = []
        if L[i] == 'A':
            for j in range(i, len(L)):
                l.append(L[j])
                if L[j] == 'B':
                    s.append(l[:])
    return s
```

which now works:

```
>>> find_substring(['C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'X', 'B', 'Y', 'A'])
[['A', 'B'], ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'X', 'B'], ['A', 'A', 'X', 'B'], ['A', 'X', 'B']]
```

Comment: Could also use a list-comp with precomputed indices of start/end and then slice, something like: `[L[a:b] for a in (idx for idx, v in enumerate(L) if v == 'A') for b in (idx for idx, v in enumerate(L, 1) if v == 'B') if a < b]`

Answer (score 1):

When you append `l` to `s`, you are adding a *reference* to a list which you then continue to grow. You want to append a *copy* of the `l` list's contents at the time when you append, to keep it static.

```
           s.append(l[:])
```

This is a common FAQ; this question should probably be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: https://sopython.com/canon/128/appending-in-a-loop-creates-a-list-of-unexpected-duplicates/ describes *exactly* this but the duplicates it proposes aren't very good for this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

You would be better first finding all indices of `'A'` and `'B'`, then iterating over those, avoiding brute force.

```
def find_substrings(lst)
    idx_A = [i for i, c in enumerate(lst) if c == 'A']
    idx_B = [i for i, c in enumerate(lst) if c == 'B']

    return [lst[i:j+1] for i in idx_A for j in idx_B if j > i]
```

Comment: Why not just build `idx_A` and `idx_B` in a single pass?

Comment: Very similar to what I posted as a comment on another answer... you could use `enumerate(lst, 1)` for `idx_B` and then avoid the `j+1` though...

Answer (score 0):

You can reset `l` to a copy of the string after l is appended `l = l[:]` right after the last append.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want all the substrings that start with 'A' and end with 'B'?

When you use @Joeidden's code you can change need the `for i in range(len(L) - 1):` to `for i in range(len(L)):` because only strings that end with 'B' will be appended to `s`.

```
def find_substring(L):
    s = []
    for i in range(len(L)):
        l = []
        if L[i] == 'A':
            for j in range(i, len(L)):
                l.append(L[j])
                if L[j] == 'B':
                    s.append(l[:])
return s
```

Answer (score 0):

Another slightly different approach would be this:

```
L = ['C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'X', 'B', 'Y', 'A']

def find_substring(L):
    output = []
    # Start searching for A.
    for i in range(len(L)):
        # If you found one start searching all B's until you reach the end.
        if L[i]=='A':
            for j in range(i,len(L),1):
                # If you found a B, append the sublist from i index to j+1 index (positions of A and B respectively).
                if L[j]=='B':
                    output.append(L[i:j+1])
    return output

result = find_substring(L)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[['A', 'B'], ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'X', 'B'], ['A', 'A', 'X', 'B'], ['A', 'X', 'B']]
```

In case you need a list comprehension of the above:

```
def find_substring(L):
    output = [L[i:j+1] for i in range(len(L)) for j in range(i,len(L),1) if L[i]=='A' and L[j]=='B']
    return output
```